# What is generally the correct procedure for publishing translations of my own work?

Tags: publications, paper-submission, translations

I am putting a paper out and would like to also put out a companion non-English language version. It will be identical, just a translation, and publishing the same content in another journal would be dishonest (or seems dishonest to me) and I don't want to do that. What is the procedure for this?

Currently, I think it best to just host the translated version on arXiv with a link to the original, but I wanted to solicit outside opinions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If during submission, you clearly state that this is a translation of paper X, then I don't see an issue. It might however be a good idea to inquire with the journal beforehand whether they do publish translations of already published papers; not all journals might do that.

Also, you need to check with the journal where the English version has been published whether their copyright allows to publish such a translation in another journal, and of which version (e.g. the pre- or post-review version). Note that this might even be a point to consider when you want to post a translation on the arxiv.

Finally, there might even exist journals where you might be able to publish both the English and the translated version in the same journal, maybe even alongside each other; this might well alleviate those copyright issues.